# How to configure Apache Ignite with multiple config files

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I need to configure Ignite with multiple caches with different names within one cluster using Spring XML. The goal is to eventually have one jar file for each cache for the ease of deployment.

- Use GridGain web console to generate the cluster configurations code for each cache. So, for example I create two jars for two different caches, each jar will have a xml file for the cache configs.
- Copied the two jars to the GridGain/libs directory.
- Started Ignite from the bin/ignite.sh. My understanding that Ignite should automatically load the two caches. It doesn't seem to do so.

I have noticed that I should pass the config path when running the ignite.sh script, however, I am not sure how to pass multiple files. Should I create a root xml file that wildcard imports multiple xml configurations from multiple locations and pass that root xml to the ignite.sh script?

Any help or suggestions on how should I approach this?

Comment: I'm afraid your basic architecture is wrong. Ignite's caches configuration should not depend on/be defined by jars present in classpath. This sounds like a magical deployment trick which will very soon start backfiring.

Comment: Well, yes, this is why I am asking for directions. How would you deploy your two different caches to the same cluster ?

Comment: I would create them from code (`Ignite.createCache()`) depending on which configuration is deployed.

Answer (score 1):

I tried below kind of solution when I had similar kind of requirement.
1- If all you want to use xml then you at least need to pass one xml specifying IgniteConfiguration bean. Please not that you can start ignite using all java config as after all xml configuration is fully convertible to java code.
2- So, when you start your node with basic IgniteConfiguration, you can load another xmls where you will have other bean configs such as CacheConfiguration. You need to load those bean using classic spring methods(to load bean from xml) and you can use that loaded bean to create cache using ignite started in step 1.